# Ubuntu 14.04 no email account

Tags: thunderbird

I thought by installing Ubuntu alongside windows I could use both windows desktop + ubuntu. I deleted Thunderbird; could not get it to work but now have no default email. It's blank. How do I get Thunderbird back or something better? I  downloaded thunderbird 2x but all I get is files on the desktop

Answer (score 1):

Go to Software Center and search for Thunderbird, or Evolution. And then click on Install button ;-)

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. it works and better than the 1st time.

Comment: You are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can just open terminal and type

`sudo apt-get install thunderbird`

to install it..... :)

Comment: After I typed the command in terminal it asked for my password but when I typed, nothing showed up and it said "sorry try again". Everytime I type nothing appears. What can I do?

Comment: you have to just type your password... You typed it wrong...!!! When you type your password into terminal, nothing appears due to security reasons.... Continue typing your password correctly....   :)

Comment: Thanks, now I understand why it didn't work and so both answers were useful.